# pass module as argument in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, passport-local

I am migrating from javascript to typescript.

To keep my code clean I spread my code in seperate files but I am having problem doing that in typescript

Folder structure :

```
App
 |- config
 |  |- passport.js
 |- server.js
```

Doing this was totally valid in javascript:

app.js(file)

```
const passport = require('passport')
const config = require('./config/passport')(passport)
//all other express code
```

config.js(file)

```
const config = (passport)=>{
//authentication login
}
module.exports = config
```

but when I try to do something similar in typescript

app.ts(file)

```
import express from 'express'
import config from './config/passport'
//all other express code
```

config.ts(file)

```
const config = (passport)=>{
//authentication login
}
export default config
```

I get this error

> Parameter 'passport' implicitly has an 'any' type

I know I can pass `passport:any` as a parameter to config function but I want type checking here

I also tried

```
import passport from 'passport'
let passportType = typeof passport
config(passport : passportType)
```

but get this error

> 'passportType' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a plain module handle that could easily be loaded on its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last example `let passportType = typeof passport` is creating a Javascript variable `passportType` with value `"object"`.  It's confusion because both Javascript and Typescript have a `typeof` operator with different meanings.

In order to create a Typescript type, you would need to use the keyword `type` instead of `let`.

```
import passport from 'passport'

type PassportType = typeof passport

const config = (passport: PassportType) => {
```

It is a bit strange that you are passing the entire `passport` module to a function rather than just using the imported `passport` in the `config` file.